# Perl code is not throwing any error

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
$b = 5;
my $var=10;
print $var;
```

Above code is not throwing error. I have not used `my` for variable `$b`.

Answer (score 10):

`$b` is a predeclared variable in Perl. It is used with [`sort()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) like so:

```
my @sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @list;
```

It is documented in [perldoc perlvar.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$b)

Comment: It is also a *package* variable, and it is inadvisable to use it.